# Determining the number of bytes used by a variable

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, memory-management

I have the following array:

```
byte[][] A = new byte[256][];
```

Each element of this array references another array.

```
A[n] = new byte[256];
```

However, most elements reference the same array. In fact, array A only references two or three unique arrays.

Is there an easy way to determine how much memory the entire thing uses?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your question is to find out the number of unique 1D arrays, you could do:

```
A.Distinct().Count()
```

This should do because equality of arrays works on reference-equality by default.

But perhaps you're looking for:

```
A.Distinct().Sum(oneDimArray => oneDimArray.Length) * sizeof(byte)
```

Of course, "number of bytes used by variables" is a somewhat imprecise term. In particular, the above expression doesn't account for the storage of the variable `A`, references in the jagged array, overhead, alignment etc.

EDIT: As Rob points out, you may need to filter `null` references out if the jagged-array can contain them.

You can estimate the cost of storing the references in the jagged-array with (`unsafe` context):

```
A.Length * sizeof(IntPtr)
```

Comment: Also need a null check: (a.Distinct().Where(aa => aa != null).Sum(aa => aa.Length) * sizeof(byte)).Dump();

Comment: Thanks. (Nice code, BTW.) I'm writing a Boyer-Moore search algorithm and looking at multi-stage tables to reduce the amount of memory used for the shift table and Unicode characters. It's working but I don't know how much memory I'm saving. So I'm also interested in the bytes used by A in addition to the referenced arrays. I guess its 4 or 8 bytes per item (depending on if 32 or 64-bit build). It doesn't look like C# can tell me that.

Comment: @Rob: In my particular case, no element will be null.

Comment: @Jonathan Wood: It can in an unsafe context; I've tried to answer that with an edit.

Comment: @Ari: This is beyond my knowledge. How do I get it to compile using constructs that can only be used in an unsafe context?

Comment: @Jonathan Wood: Did you mean *safe* context? `A.Length * sizeof(IntPtr)` will work if you mark the containing method with the `unsafe` modifier.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there's any built in functionality.

Whipped this up very quickly, haven't tested it throughly however;

```
void Main()
{
    byte[][] a = new byte[256][];
    var someArr = new byte[256];
    a[0] = someArr;
    a[1] = someArr;
    a[2] = new byte[256];
    getSize(a).Dump();
}

private long getSize(byte[][] arr)
{
    var hashSet = new HashSet<byte[]>();
    var size = 0;
    foreach(var innerArray in arr)
    {
        if(innerArray != null)
            hashSet.Add(innerArray);
    }

    foreach (var array in hashSet)
    {
        size += array.Length * sizeof(byte);
    }
    return size;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just a modified Rob's getSize method to use the Buffer helper class.

```
private long getSize(byte[][] arr)
{
    Dictionary<byte[], bool> lookup = new Dictionary<byte[], bool>();

    long size = 0;

    foreach (byte[] innerArray in arr)
    {
        if (innerArray == null || lookup.ContainsKey(innerArray)) continue;
        lookup.Add(innerArray, true);
        size += Buffer.ByteLength(innerArray);
    }

    return size;
}
```

Comment: I get the error `Object must be an array of primitives.` on the call to ByteLength().

Comment: @Jonathan Wood, the innerArray is an array of bytes and the byte is a primitive type. Are you passing in arr? or are you using a type other than byte?

Comment: Yes, you're right. It works with just the plain byte[] array. For a byte[256], it returns (surprise) 256.